# Tkinter Get Value and then Destroy

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create an app that has 2 windows. The first window (A) is only called the first time the app is ran, and then opens window (B). For all future events, only window (B) is called. This is the following code:

```
# Script Counter/Setup
def read_counter():
    if path.exists("counter.json"):
        return loads(open("counter.json", "r").read()) + 1
    else:
        info = tk.Tk()
        info.title("Setup")
        info.geometry("350x120")
        info.grid_columnconfigure((0, 2), weight = 1)

        count = tk.Label(info, text = "Previous Post Number")
        string = tk.StringVar()
        count_input = tk.Entry(info, textvariable = string)
        val = string.get()

        def destroy_get():
            val = int(count_input.get())
            info.quit()
            return val

        count_button = tk.Button(info, text = "Done!", command = destroy_get)

        tk.Label(info, text = "Setup", font='Helvetica 18 bold').grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        count.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        count_input.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        count_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5)
        info.mainloop()
        # info.destroy()
        return destroy_get()

def write_counter():
    with open("counter.json", "w") as f:
        f.write(dumps(counter))

counter = read_counter()
atexit.register(write_counter)

folders = ["to_post/", "not_posted/", "posted"]
for folder in folders:
    if not path.exists(folder):
        os.mkdir(folder)

print(os.getcwd())
# GUI
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Confessions Bot")
window.geometry("600x350")
window.grid_columnconfigure((0,2), weight = 1)

label_tell_account = tk.Label(window, text = "Tellonym Account")
label_tell_password = tk.Label(window, text = "Tellonym Password")
label_ig_account = tk.Label(window, text = "Instagram Account")
label_ig_password = tk.Label(window, text = "Instagram Password")

tell_account = tk.Entry(window)
tell_password = tk.Entry(window)
ig_account = tk.Entry(window)
ig_password = tk.Entry(window)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png"))
tk.Label(window, image = image).grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)
label_tell_account.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
tell_account.grid(row = 1, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
label_tell_password.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
tell_password.grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
label_ig_account.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
ig_account.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
label_ig_password.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10)
ig_password.grid(row = 4, column = 2, padx = 10, pady = 10)
# run.grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

window.mainloop()
```

When this is ran I get `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist`. I read that this happens since I haven't destroyed my initial window. If I change `destroy_get()` to have `info.destroy()` I'm no longer able to get the the entry from window A.

This is my first time using Tkinter and coding in general so any help is welcome.

Comment: You are seeing some of the numerous problems from calling `Tk()` more than once in a program.  Use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Comment: The error is because your having mutiple instances of `Tk()`. Only use `Tk()` for main window and replace every subwindows with `Toplevel()`

Comment: Even when I replace `Tk` with `Toplevel()` I have the same issue

Comment: It is because `read_counter()` is called before `window = tk.Tk()`.  When `info = tk.Topleve()` is called, there is no instance of `Tk` and so a default one will be created.  So still two instances of `Tk`.